# Flutter in-app-purchase non-renewing-subscription

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I want to make a periodic pass item(ex: 1 week pass, 1 month pass) for remove ads and access premium contents to user.

I saw Android has `consumable`, `non-consumable`, `subscription`.
And IOS has `consumable`, `non-consumable`, `auto-renewable-subscription`, `non-renewable-subscription`.
But in Flutter's In-App-Purchase, there's only two options: `consumable` and `none-consumable`.

How can I implement this to flutter app in Android and IOS both with In-App-Purchase?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your custom logic for it that will will work fine. I will suggest you to go with cron package to make the periodic tasks over android side workmanager is the best but it doesnt works over ios side but cron does. Alternatively you can get the work done with firebase schedule functions but its a bad approach the best one is cron with flutter in app purchase I've done similar task with over ios side as well.

Comment: I'm currently using `In-App-Purchase` plugin. And I have to check purchase data like when user bought it from Google Play or App Store. Because I'm trying to not add any login to my app. Can I get any purchasement Info?

Answer (score 0):

Android and IOS both with In-App-Purchase with auto-renew working best and easy way in Revenuecat plugin
Link  https://docs.flutterflow.io/advanced-functionality/payments/revenuecat